# extracting data from JSON for a given path using Play JSON

Tags: scala, play-json

I'm trying to create a function, that takes Json string and path as an input, and returns the data in that path, for e.g. to extract the `id` field from the below JSON using Scala, using the path `"employee/id"`

```
val json = {
  "employee" : {
    "id" : "12345",
    "department" : "Finance"
    }
}


def extractData(json: String, path: String) // returns data for the given path
extractData(json, "employee/id") // returns "12345"
```

I'm able to extract directly using the code,

```
val data = Json.parse(jsonData) / "employee" / "id"
```

I want to extract the data, without hard coding the path, I tried using the below code

```
val path = "employee/id"
val levels = path.split('/')
val data = levels.foldLeft(parsedJson)((acc, level) => (acc \ level))
```

I'm getting, `Type mismatch` error. I also tried, using other methods with mutable states.
Is there any functional way to do this in Scala?

```
Scala version = 2.12.10
Play json version = 2.9.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert type `JsValue` to `JsLookupResult`. You can make it like this:

```
  val jsonTest = """{
                   |  "employee" : {
                   |    "id" : "12345",
                   |    "department" : "Finance"
                   |    }
                   |}""".stripMargin

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val x = extractData(jsonTest, "employee/id").as[String]
    println(x)
  }

  def extractData(json: String, path: String): JsLookupResult = {
    val jsValue: JsValue = Json.parse(json)
    path.split("/").foldLeft(jsValue.result) { (acc, el) =>
      acc \ el
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use `.validate` rather than `.as`